# startActivity with YouTubeStandalonePlayer intent makes MainActivity be created

Tags: android, android-intent, actionbarsherlock, android-youtube-api, start-activity

When I call startActivityForResult (or startActivity) the "onCreate" of the MainActivity is being called even before the new activity is created. **It doesn't happen with other intents**.

This is the code inside click handler of a button in a listview that has an adapter (inside a fragment inside a tab of SherlockActionBar):

```
            ((MainActivity)context).setVideoId(v.getTag().toString());
            Intent videoIntent = YouTubeStandalonePlayer.createVideoIntent((Activity) context, "AIzaSyC1sF6kq9hHGrQvRSiU8Ks5iYfVCbdg7zA", v.getTag().toString(), 0, true, false);
            ((Activity)context).startActivityForResult(videoIntent, 12);
```

and this is the constructor of the adapter:

```
    public ItemAdapter(Context c, int textViewResourceId) {
    super(c, textViewResourceId);
    this.layoutResourceId = textViewResourceId;
    this.context = c;
```

Comment: What do you mean onCreate() of the MainActivity is being called before the new activity is created? What error are you getting?

Comment: I'm not getting an error now, but it is making problems. when I call StartActivity with the YouTube intent, it seems like the MainActivity is created (the onCreate of the MainActivity is called), and then the YouTube's activity is shown. when I click the Back button of the device, the MainActivity is created again. If i change the code and starts some other activity (not youtube's), then the MainActivity is not being created again. the getFlags() of the youtube's intent returns 0. Hope it's more clear now.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's happened because activity change orientation. Add this in the manifest:

```
<activity
android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize|keyboardHidden"
...
```

Comment: You're right but what you suggest prevents the option to change orientation to my activity.

Comment: No, you can only add 
android: configChanges = "orientation | screenSize | keyboardHidden" 
it will not recreate the activity after changing screen orientation